# Extraneous whitespace in close dialog in Safari

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog, safari, whitespace

In Safari (16.0) on macOS ([12.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey)), the close dialog has some additional whitespace above the title - it seems to be aligned with the bottom of the close icon:

[image]

On other my browsers (Firefox, Chrome) it looks fine:

[image]

Comment: Also happens on iPhone (even when there is clearly enough space for both on the same line).

Comment: It begs the question whether or not Safari is a real browser...