# Close vote window explanation text is too small

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog

Close vote dialog text under each close vote option is very small and it is very hard to read.

[image: Close vote dialog]

I am not sure whether I noticed this due to recent color change, which makes the text color lighter or the font size has also been changed.

Anyway, regardless of what brought this to my attention the font is simply to small for comfortable reading. Having darker font color wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Was it always like that, or only after the recent design change?

Comment: I don't believe those colours have changed.

Comment: @Joachim well they have also changed more things, not just colors.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry I noticed that I cannot read it anymore after yesterday's color change. And going though other questions here about the dialog it seems that both font size and color has changed. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382231/extraneous-whitespace-in-close-dialog-in-safari

Comment: The font size has not changed. The colour is nearly unreadably dim, though.